# Overwrite log line with log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

is it possible with log4j2 to overwrite a logline?
So for example instead of logging

```
19:43:44.642 [main] INFO  main - Init...
19:43:50.348 [main] INFO  main - Init done.
```

one can log first

```
19:43:44.642 [main] INFO  main - Init...
```

and when the init is done instead of writing a new line rewriting the last line like (either rewrite or just append)

```
19:43:44.642 [main] INFO  main - Init... - done.
```

I am aware of the fact that the timestamp gets messed up as it is now incorrect (at least if it is not updated aswell in the case of appending).

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I think, it is, but you'd have to dig deeper into log4j, write your own [log appender](https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-custom-appender) and configure the log system accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible. The log system is not a console. Logs output is dumped on the file system in the stream. It was done from performance perspective.
The case you described more related to console behavior.
So this is not proper approach for using logging at all.